# How to insert &nbsp in a @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EventDetailSection.ContactAccountTel)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, displayfor

Currently, I'm using the `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.EventDetailSection.ContactAccountTel)`, but this will output a regular number without any spaces in between like: `+3194949494`, I'd like to add spaces after 2 numbers and then 3. How can I achieve this, do I have to use Splice?

Answer (score 0):

my friend. I think you can use Substring() or Insert() method for this.

Just set the data of property before display on View.
Here is a sample. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
public class MyModel
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

var model = new MyModel { Number = "+3194949494" };            
model.Number = model.Number != null ? model.Number.Insert(3, " ").Insert(7, " ") : string.Empty;

<h1>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Number)</h1>
```

Or change on View

```
@{
    Model.Number = Model.Number != null ? Model.Number.Insert(3, " ").Insert(7, " ") : string.Empty;
    <h1>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Number)</h1>
}
```

Comment: Hi ,thanks for your answer. Is there a way to change it in the view itself? I don't have access to the model and the number is able to change. The phone number is a variable which is bound to change for the specific user. I'm only able to change on the view itself.

Comment: @DidiZhou: I updated my answer. Sorry for late response, my friend.